# I'm trying to write a Pig Latin translator that takes in a whole sentence and translates every word

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried using `.split()` to translate whole sentences word for word, but it only returns the first word translated followed by the rest of the words with 'ay' at the end.

This is what I have so far (this only translates one word at a time).
I have an if statement to detect any spaces given in the input. (I deleted the if statement when I tried to program it to translate sentences)

```
word_to_translate = input(
    "Give me a word that you'd like me to translate into Pig Latin?\n\t"
    )

def piglatin(prompt):
    '''
    DOC: To find the first letter of prompt, and determine if it's a vowel or not.
    Then use the string 'ay' to create a pig latin word
    Input: Example - "peyton"
    Output: Example - "Eytonpay"
    '''
    # grabbing first letter of prompt
    first_letter = prompt[0]

    # check if vowel
    if first_letter in 'aeiou' :
        translation = prompt + 'ay'

    else :
        translation = prompt[1:] + first_letter + 'ay'

    return translation.capitalize()
```

What do I need to do to translate sentences?

Comment: You don't show us the code with `split`, so I'm not sure how we could figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a coding or tutorial resource.  Post your coding attempt.  You need to break the sentence into words, and then iterate through the words.  These items are covered quite well in available tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One statement:

```py
def piglatin(sentence):
    return ' '.join(map(
        lambda str: str + 'ay' if str[0] in 'aeiou' else str[1:] + str[0] + 'ay',
        sentence.split(' ')
    ))
```

Avoid using/submitting this code unless you understand it. Let's go from the inside out:

We use a ternary statement `str + 'ay' if str[0] in 'aeiou' else str[1:] + str[0] + 'ay'` to perform the piglatin manipulation. Then we put this in a lambda (basically an inline function) and use `map` to apply the function to each one of the words (words generated with `.split`). Lastly, we rejoin the sentence with the space character.

Comment: Thanks. This helps a lot. I'm still new to python and programming in general. If this question doesn't belong on Stack Overflow, then what the hell is the site for? This isn't necessarily homework either. It's something I'm creating for a class that has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: "Homework question" is just a catch-all for questions that ask others to write code with no source provided. I'm not sure why I wrote that honestly, your question was fine. Perhaps next time don't put any details that aren't relevant to the code itself ("for school", "Let me know..."). Welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks again. Now, If I were to want to capitalize the first letter of the translation, where would I need to write .capitalize? I tried it before .join and before .split. Neither worked. For that matter, where would I use .capitalize on any input question?

Comment: You'd do .capitalize after the entire joining, i.e. `' '.join(...).capitalize()`.

Comment: '<built-in method capitalize of str object at 0x000002B8AE12C970>' This is what i get back after everything I've tried including .join(...).capitalize

Comment: I figured it out haha. I seem to leave out () all of the time

Comment: `map()` and a lambda? Why not just use a list comprehension, especially since we’re using it as input to `str.join()`?

Comment: That might have been a better solution, you are correct, but there's nothing inherently wrong with a `map()` (besides not being preferred over list comprehensions). Also, being an input to `str.join()` doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what the question is about, but if you're looking for a way to apply your piglatin() function on every word of the prompt split() is indeed the right choice, combined with list comprahension:

```
[piglatin(word) for word in prompt.split(' ')]
```